# Show that the double torus i.e. genus $2$ torus retracts to the genus $1$ torus.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Show that the double torus i.e. genus $2$ torus retracts to the genus $1$ torus.

The identification space of the double torus is

[image]

and the identification space of the genus $1$ torus is

[image]

but I don't see how I can get from the first one to the second by a retraction? Both of these spaces contain the interiors, but they have different fundamental groups so they're not homotopy equivalent. So this retraction would not be a deformation retraction. I'm not looking for an explicit mapping just the idea.

Comment: How is a genus 1 torus a subspace of a genus 2 torus? Where is the problem from?

Comment: Is it not? I found a stronger result which stated that a orientable genus $g$ surface $M_g$ can be retracted to $M_1$ so I tried to approach it with $g = 2$.

Comment: As @runway44 said, a torus isn't a subspace of a double torus, so a retraction can't be constructed... is the retraction here defined as something else?

Comment: I foud the following paragraph. "We think of $M_g$ as a $4g$-sided polygon with side identifications going around clockwise $$a_1,b_1, a_1^{-1}, b_1^{-1}, \dots, a_{2g}^{-1}, b_{2g}^{-1}$$ Then we make the identification $a_i = a_1$ and $b_i = b_1$. The quotient map of this identification is then a retract $M_g \to M_1$, that is, a retract to the torus."

Comment: The edges of the polygon correspond to a graph within the surface. You've described a quotient map from the wedge of four circles on the double torus to the wedge of two circles on the torus, but I don't see how those maps extend to the interior of the polygon / rest of the surface. Even if you could, to be a retract you still need to see how the torus is a subspace of the double torus in the first place, which is how exactly? Also, what source are your quotes from?